# Find the correct zoom of a google places search and redirect the user to another page with a map, centering and zooming the map accordingly

Tags: google-maps

I have two pages. 
On the first page, there is a google searchbox.
On the second page, there is the google map.

When the user searches for a place on the map, I get it's lat and lng and send the user to the second page, setting the map's center to that location.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.sb, 'places_changed', function() {

        var place = this.getPlaces()[0],
            viewport,
            lat,
            lng;

        if (place) {
            lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            lng =  place.geometry.location.lng();
            // viewport = place.geometry.viewport;

            // sessionStorage.setItem('sViewport', JSON.stringify(viewport));

            // How can I find out the proper zoom for this search and se it as a query string param?

            window.location.href= 'rezultate.html?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng.toString()+'&zoom=?????????;
            return;
        }
        $('.search-error').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

**The problem is I cannot find a way to get the proper zoom for that search.**

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by "proper zoom" and what are you trying to achieve here? also please mention the maps api version that you are using.

Comment: According to this https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/search_and_zoom, they set zoom to 10  .setZoom(10);

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is the place's geometry's **viewport** bounds rather than the place location.

If you use those coordinates to fit bounds on your map, you will get the correct viewport for that place.

Example:

`const viewportBounds = place.geometry.viewport;`